# What is the procedural mysqli way of preparing SQL statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a SQL query in my code that I want to convert to a prepared statement to stop vulnerabilities like SQL injections. So this is what I want to convert:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * from `wp_posts` WHERE ID=$pid ";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    //$id=$row['Gallery_Id'];

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
    <h2 align="center"> <?php echo $row['post_title']; ?> </h2><br>
    <div class="paracenter">

        <p id="cont"><?php echo $row['post_content']; ?></p>
        <hr color="black" width="10%">

    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work.

```
$query = "SELECT * from `wp_posts` WHERE ID=? ";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
    if($stmt){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $pid);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $dbpid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    //$id=$row['Gallery_Id'];

    while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)){
        ?>


    <h2 align="center"> <?php echo $row['post_title']; ?> </h2><br>
    <div class="paracenter">

        <p id="cont"><?php echo $row['post_content']; ?></p>
        <hr color="black" width="10%">

    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Almost all the examples online doesn't use the procedural method I use. How can I rectify this?

Comment: The manual has OOP and procedural styles. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php What happens currently

Comment: Yeah, the examples there simply uses the defined variables to output. It doesn't mention how to get values when the query is `SELECT *` @chris85

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and apply that to your query.

Comment: you got it all jumbled up, you're mixing `*i_query()` and the prepared statements api

Comment: @Ghost, can you tell me how to correct it please?

Answer (score -1):

Explicitly select the columns that you will later fetch instead of using `*` in your SELECT clause.

Parameter bindingly is by reference, so the `$pid` must be declared then use -- as opposed to directly writing the integer `2` directly into the bind call.

When binding the result, offer variables which correlate to the columns in your SELECT clause.

Code: ([PHPize.online Demo](https://phpize.online/s/9C))

```
$pid = 2;

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT post_title, post_content
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID=?
SQL;

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $pid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $title, $content);

if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    ?>
    <h2 align="center"><?php echo $title; ?></h2><br>
    <div class="paracenter">
        <p id="cont"><?php echo $content; ?></p>
        <hr color="black" width="10%">
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

---

That said, you are coding inside of a Wordpress application and Wordpress has its own helper methods to offer prepared statement functionality (though it is not in procedural syntax, it is attractively tidy).

```
$row = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql, [$pid]));
if ($row) {
    ?>
    <h2 align="center"><?php echo $title; ?></h2><br>
    <div class="paracenter">
        <p id="cont"><?php echo $content; ?></p>
        <hr color="black" width="10%">
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

---

And finally, it is probably most advisable to use the dedicated Wordpress function `get_post()`.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/

```
$post = get_post($pid);
// $post->post_title;
// $post->post_content;
```

Comment: I'd love to hear what is incorrect with my answer so that I can improve it.